# Is there a way to use item weight in a Shopping Cart Price Rule condition?

Tags: magento, conditional-statements, coupon, promotion-code

I have a product that has two weights options, 1lbs and 2lbs. Is it possible to set a Shopping Cart Price Rule condition for only the 2lbs item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a best way to apply Shopping Cart Price Rule condition.

1. add new attribute (Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes)
   ex)item_att_weight
   at the properties :  Input type = dropdown, Use for Promo Rule Conditions = yes.. (others can be set you want)

[image]

2. set weight value at the Manage Label / Options

[image]

3. New attribute that you made add to attribute set (Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes Sets)
4. When you add a product, have to use Configurable Product and select attribute set that you made.

under Shopping Cart Price rules.

5. setup condition whatever you want
6. Go to Actions and setup conditions as below

   - Select attribute "item_att_weight" that you made
   - Select Value 2(lb)

[image]

then It should be worked as you desired. I hope it helps you...

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it's a configurable product with two options based on an attribute ?
You juste have to set your shopping cart price rule on the second product by selected the sku of this product.